# How to stop rain from entering at the cuffs of my rain jacket?

Tags: gear, rain, rain-gear

So this is one of those things that I've grown so accustomed to that I've not really put any effort or thought into looking for a solution. I've just "dealt with it" to the point of ignoring it for so long now.

Almost all rain jackets provide an adjustable cuff via velcro or other means to cinch up around the wrist, but this barely impedes the invasion of moisture at that point. **What is a method or piece of gear that will prevent water from dripping down the hands and wrist into the cuffs of a rain jacket when hands are horizontal or reaching above?** Gloves are a quick thought but they will capture water when your hands are down and are unlikely to be worn in warm weather.

*Just to head this one off: please no "buy a new rain jacket" answers. Even the best rain jackets will have this problem.*

Comment: Your assumption about buying a new jacket may be incorrect; just as some pajamas come with feet, there was a recent Kickstarter for a jacket with integrated gloves.

Comment: That may be, but millions of people already have traditional rain jackets. Something that will help people without having to purchase another jacket would be ideal.

Comment: Don't put your hands in the air to let water in?

Comment: @ShemSeger - That would be nice, but not always an option, especially if climbing or belaying in some way or another (not rock climbing).

Comment: If you can't solve a problem using [gaffer tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaffer_tape) there is a fair chance you're not using enough gaffer tape....

Answer (score 9):

I've never had too much trouble with a double cuff - a velcro or (better) elastic inner cuff and a loose outer. In the worst conditions, an elasticated inner cuff under a goretex glove with long elasticated wrist seals was good for anything short of immersion.

In the worst case a watersports dry cag would solve this. They have latex or neoprene wrist seals.

They're also rather impractical as rain jackets. Using them for inspiration instead might be better. My dry suit had slightly slack wrist seals for me. By cutting rings of spare latex wrist seals (like fat stiff rubber bands) and putting them over the top, the problem was solved. In fact just rubber bands would help and is an old-fashioned solution. If you have thin wrists or a bike with fat tyres, some bands of old inner tubes would do the trick. They could overlap the end of the sleeve and any glove as a sort of wrist gaiter.

Any tight wrist seal will make you hot.

Comment: I like your idea of repurposing something to make a "wrist gaiter." This is kind  of like an idea I was brainstorming but hadn't found anything really to use yet.

Comment: A pair of latex drysuit wrist seals is cheap on eBay and they can be cut with good scissors. You might be able to get neoprene seals (more expensive but more comfortable).

Answer (score 5):

While working outside in the rain and when wearing a rain jacket, I have two simple solutions for keeping as dry as possible when the weather is miserable. I do not wear wrist bands because I like to have some ventilation. You cannot stop water from creeping inside, so I use latex gloves inside my regular gloves, this way my hands are reasonably dry. The second thing I do (only if the temperature is warm enough) is that I roll up my shirt sleeves to just past my elbows. At least this way I am able to stay dry. This little trick I've used for several years now and it works quite nicely. When I take my rain jacket off at least I am dry, although I will be a little humid. Rain gear in general is not breathable.

Note: If one is really desperate, there is the possibility of putting on [long veterinary gloves](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/long-veterinary-glove.html) under your rain jacket!

Comment: Don't you have to wear outer gloves that are at least one size larger when you wear the latex gloves?  (if they don't fit.....)

Comment: @ab2 No. Latex gloves are quite thin, so I can wear my normal size gloves. Nevertheless, one of the guys at work wares extra long gloves, but does not wear latex gloves underneath.

Comment: I can see how the glove idea would work for some, but my hands would quite certainly be wet from sweating inside them. But rolling up sleeves to keep clothing dry is a good tip.

Answer (score 3):

As a Scot I did a lot of wet climbing, so am pretty familiar with the issue you've asked about!

I was careful to buy jackets with a good cuff, and I'd use absorbent sweat-bands on my wrists just inside the cuff to mop up any leakage.

I'd also roll or ruck up the arms of my inner layers so they were above the sweat bands and stayed pretty dry.

In torrential conditions, you might have to wring out the sweatbands every now and again on the belays!

If your jacket has a poor cuff, Chris H's idea of a rubber seal might be your best option - on its own or in combination with wrist bands. Though it will cut out all ventilation which causes its own issues with damp.